# Oracle Procedure RowType with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I have a locked down database with a somewhat useful API, however i'm struggling with a final call to retrieve a value.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_ne_Id number;
begin
v_ne_id := package.get_str('10800002').str_ne_id;
dbms_output.put_line(v_ne_id);
end;
/
```

The above code through SQL plus gets my result perfectly, however I am using this in a .net application. How can i retrieve the value in asp.net?

I've tried direct coding the above pl/SQL but this doesnt return any value.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I figured it out... this may or may not help someone.

```
String SQL = " ";

            SQL += " begin ";
            SQL += " :v_ne_id := package.get_str('10800002').str_ne_id; ";
            SQL += "  ";
            SQL += " end;";

            OracleParameter p_description = new OracleParameter();
            p_description.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            p_description.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
            p_description.Value = "";
            p_description.ParameterName = "v_ne_id";

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleconnection.thisConnString()))
            {
                connection.Open();

                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(SQL, connection);


                command.Parameters.Add(p_description);


                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            return p_description.Value.ToString();
```